# Where is my top padding?

Tags: css

I have an CSS issue with a menu.

Through CSS I´ve added padding to `li`'s.

The `li`'s have `display: inline`.

It works when I set to `inline-block`, but I want to know why it doesn't work with `inline`. In my understanding padding should work with inline elements.

HTML

```
<header>
<nav>
  <ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Rankings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">In the press</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
body { font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
header nav { height: 25px; background: #eeeeee; }
header nav ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 960px; }
header nav li { display: inline; padding: 10px 5px; }
```

Working demo

http://jsfiddle.net/4QLmp/

PS browser is Chrome Canary

Comment: why would you want to test in a buggy and untested nightly browser?

Comment: @balexandre: I don't think it is Canary or even browser specific. Just wanted to note to be sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The padding is there, but since the `<li>`s are defined as inline, they're aligned to the same text baseline. That cuts off the top padding beyond the top of the page border. If you do change the css to:

> header nav li { display: inline; padding: 20px 5px; border: 1px solid red; position: relative; top: 50px;}

so that the `<ul>`s get pushed down, you'll see the padding present. inline-block doesn't follow the same text-alignment rules, so everything gets pushed down so the whole block is visible.

Answer (score -1):

```
header nav li { display: inline; padding: 10px 5px; }
```

UPD:

The W3C’s CSS2 spec states that for Inline, non-replaced elements, "the ‘height’ property doesn’t apply, but the height of the box is given by the ‘line-height’ property".

Comment: sorry. The W3C’s CSS2 spec states that for Inline, non-replaced elements, "the ‘height’ property doesn’t apply, but the height of the box is given by the ‘line-height’ property".

Comment: you can use line-height to achieve same result

Comment: You set padding for inline element, this is not correct.

But you can use "line-height", to make element displayed in the middle of the box, i.e. if you have font-size:12px, use something like line-height:24px;

Comment: It is perfectly fine to use padding for inline elements. The thing to note is that in will not have an effect on surrounding elements. However it HAS effect on the element itself. See the red div in the example: http://jsfiddle.net/4QLmp/8/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4786/discussion-between-pomaxa-and-peehaa)